# Login Error On Xorg (Kernel Module Load Failed) But Works On Wayland

Tags: 18.04, kernel, xorg, login, wayland

So, I had broken system update, and now in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. At first, I cannot login at all on any login options Ubuntu, Ubuntu in wayland, Unity. Then I don't know but somehow I'm able to login using "Ubuntu in wayland", and start updating using:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
```

And rebooted.

Then I'm able to login on wayland. However, every time I'm trying to login using Xorg (the default one), it's always got `Failed to load kernel module` error, and then back to login screen.